# language for windows 8 application ..?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8

I am very familiar with C#. Now i have to do  new project based on windows 8 application.

I have gone through [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br211386.aspx). This can be done in two ways - using javascript/HTML and C#/XAML. I cant judge which one I have to follow.

Can anybody suggest me c# or javascript is better?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on if you want to make a desktop application or a strictly Metro application. Also, opinionated questions like this are not best served to the community. So, please be wary when asking them.

Personally, I like c# but that is an OPINION and thus this question is impossible to answer with absolute authority.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know C#, I would recommend you to go ahead with same. Javascript can be quirky some times.